# LinkedIn subscription link

Tags: browser, hyperlink, linkedin-api

I'm looking for subscription link for linkedin. In order to create a link that people can tap and immediately be prompted to subscribe, we can simply add this to the link :

```
?sub_confirmation=1
```

For example :

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/SOMETHINGHERE?sub_confirmation=1
```

Is there the same thing for Linkedin ?

Some help would be appreciated